# TikZ animations key `end on` is interpreted as `begin on`

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, svg, dvisvgm

[PGF/TikZ Manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-animations) describes a key called `/tikz/animate/options/end on`. I understood that it should define a trigger for ending the timeline. However, I haven't been able to make it work. When I try to use it, it seems to begin the timeline instead of ending it.

I have the following document called `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle] (node) {node 1};
    \node :stage = {base = "false", 0s="true", 1000s="false", begin on = {mouse over, of=node}, end on = {mouse out, of=node} }
    [fill = red!20, draw = red, ultra thick, circle] at (2,2) {node 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I then compile it using `latex test.tex` and then convert to svg using `dvisvgm -n test.dvi`.

The intended behavior is to have `node 2` appear when I move the mouse pointer over `node 1` and then disappear when I move the pointer out. However, both mouse over and mouse out apparently work as triggers for displaying `node 2`.

The resulting svg has a line like this:

```
<animate attributeName='visibility' begin='pgf0.mouseover +0.0s;pgf0.mouseout +0.0s' calcMode='spline' dur='1000.0' keySplines='0 0 1 1' keyTimes='0.0;1.0' values='visible;hidden' xlink:href='#pgf2'/>
```

but I think the output should be like this:

```
<animate attributeName='visibility' begin='pgf0.mouseover +0.0s' end='pgf0.mouseout +0.0s' calcMode='spline' dur='1000.0' keySplines='0 0 1 1' keyTimes='0.0;1.0' values='visible;hidden' xlink:href='#pgf2'/>
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I'm using TeX Live 2023 on Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bug for me because both keys do the same in [the source](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/42bd29bdd61beae8d9b46f8f83505d15e301ae02/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryanimations.code.tex#L486-L487):

```
\tikzanimateset{
  options/.cd,
  ⋮
  begin on/.code=\tikz@anim@event{begin}{#1},
  end on/.code=\tikz@anim@event{begin}{#1},
  ⋮
}
```

But we can fix it.

### Code

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvisvgm
\documentclass[dvisvgm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\makeatletter
\tikzanimateset{options/end on/.code=\tikz@anim@event{end}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill = blue!20, draw = blue, ultra thick, circle] (node) {node 1};
\node :stage = {base = "false", 0s="true", 1000s="false",
                begin on = {mouse over, of=node}, end on = {mouse out, of=node}}
     [fill = red!20, draw = red, ultra thick, circle] at (2,2) {node 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [#1273](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1273)